# Notify users only on post publish

Tags: php, functions, wp-mail

I am using this function to notify users when their post is published. However, repeated emails are being sent when the post is updated. I only want to send 1 email when the post is published first and then not sent more emails if the post is subsequently updated.

```
function notifyauthor($post_id) {

$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";

$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",

      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

      "
      ;

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `transition_post_status` hook instead, as it already knows what the current and previous status of the post are.

```
<?php
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse_366380_email_on_publish', 10, 3);
function wpse_366380_email_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    // Only if this post was just published, and previously it was either
    // "auto-draft" (brand new) or "pending" (not yet published)
    if ( 'publish' == $new_status && ( 'auto-draft' == $old_status || 'pending' == $old_status ) ) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
        $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.",
        Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
        View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."";
        wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: made2popular's code suggestion to check that "publish" doesn't equal the old status makes that part of the conditional even simpler. And it gives an example of only triggering the emails for one certain post type which may be helpful depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You have used "publish_post" hook, it will fire both when a post is first transitioned to that status from something else, as well as upon subsequent post updates (old and new status are both the same).

Instead you should use "transition_post_status" hook. It fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another. You can learn more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/

Also look at this sample code: 

`function wpdocs_run_on_publish_only( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( ( 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status )
        && 'my-custom-post-type' === $post->post_type
    ) {
            // do stuff
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpdocs_run_on_publish_only', 10, 3 );`